# Error installing CNTK - MemoryError while installing .whl file

Tags: cntk

I have Ubuntu 16.04 server environment and was trying to install CNTK on it.  While I was trying to install **pip install in an environment** section I get the following error.

I succesfully ran below 2 steps:

$ conda create --name cntk-py34 python=3.4 numpy scipy h5py jupyter

$ activate cntk-py35

But when I try to install the cntk whl file I get an error:

$ pip install https://cntk.ai/PythonWheel/CPU-Only/cntk-2.0.beta15.0-cp35-cp35m-linux_x86_64.whl

========error==================

Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/.conda/envs/cntk-py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.conda/envs/cntk-py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 335, in run
    wb.build(autobuilding=True)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.conda/envs/cntk-py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 749, in build
    self.requirement_set.prepare_files(self.finder)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.conda/envs/cntk-py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 380, in prepare_files
    ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))
  File "/home/ubuntu/.conda/envs/cntk-py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 620, in _prepare_file
    session=self.session, hashes=hashes)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.conda/envs/cntk-py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/download.py", line 821, in unpack_url
    hashes=hashes
  File "/home/ubuntu/.conda/envs/cntk-py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/download.py", line 659, in unpack_http_url
    hashes)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.conda/envs/cntk-py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/download.py", line 853, in _download_http_url
    stream=True,
  File "/home/ubuntu/.conda/envs/cntk-py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/sessions.py", line 488, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.conda/envs/cntk-py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/download.py", line 386, in request
    return super(PipSession, self).request(method, url, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.conda/envs/cntk-py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/sessions.py", line 475, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.conda/envs/cntk-py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/sessions.py", line 596, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.conda/envs/cntk-py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/_vendor/cachecontrol/adapter.py", line 37, in send
    cached_response = self.controller.cached_request(request)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.conda/envs/cntk-py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/_vendor/cachecontrol/controller.py", line 111, in cached_request
    resp = self.serializer.loads(request, cache_data)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.conda/envs/cntk-py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/_vendor/cachecontrol/serialize.py", line 114, in loads
    return getattr(self, "_loads_v{0}".format(ver))(request, data)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.conda/envs/cntk-py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/_vendor/cachecontrol/serialize.py", line 176, in _loads_v2
    cached = json.loads(zlib.decompress(data).decode("utf8"))
MemoryError

Any ideas???

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

In your question, you mention two different Python versions (3.4 and 3.5). Also, the Anaconda Environment activation needs to be sourced. Assuming you already satisfied the OpenMPI dependency (cf. https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/wiki/Setup-Linux-Python), can you try one of these:

```
# For a Python 3.4 based setup
conda create --name cntk-py34 python=3.4 numpy scipy h5py jupyter
source activate cntk-py34
pip install https://cntk.ai/PythonWheel/CPU-Only/cntk-2.0rc1-cp34-cp34m-linux_x86_64.whl

# For a Python 3.5 based setup
conda create --name cntk-py35 python=3.5 numpy scipy h5py jupyter
source activate cntk-py35
pip install https://cntk.ai/PythonWheel/CPU-Only/cntk-2.0rc1-cp35-cp35m-linux_x86_64.whl
```